# Time difference between two time showing wrong values in js

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I want to check time difference between two times and get difference in minutes, using javascript and my time format is 12 hrs with am/pm

for example :

compare  minutes difference between (10:35 am) -(01:15 pm)= ? minutes

But the problem is I am getting wrong  values for this, so how to calculate  minutes between two time  using javascript

```
<script>

var timeStart = new Date("01/23/2020 " + "05:00 AM");
var timeEnd = new Date("01/23/2020 " + "06:30 PM");

var diff = (timeEnd - timeStart) / 60000; 

var minutes = diff % 60;
var hours = (diff - minutes) / 60;
alert(minutes);
alert(hours);

</script>
```

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` is the only [specified](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) format that `Date()` (and `Date.parse()`) understand. Anything else is implementation dependent and should not be relied on. Use one of the many date libraries out there (e.g. [momentjs](https://momentjs.com))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Could be the Short and Sweet solution

```js
var diff = Math.abs(new Date('01/23/2020 06:30 PM') - new Date('01/23/2020 05:00 AM'));
var minutes = Math.floor((diff/1000)/60);
alert(minutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Total minutes will be calculated as

```
var timeStart = new Date("01/23/2020 " + "05:00 AM");
var timeEnd = new Date("01/23/2020 " + "06:30 PM");

var diff = (timeEnd - timeStart) / 60000; 

var minutes = diff % 60;
var hours = (diff - minutes) / 60;
var totalMinutes = (hours*60)+minutes;
alert(totalMinutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

this will give approximate minute diff in utc.

```
let startTime = new Date("01/23/2020 " + "05:00 AM");
let endTime = new Date("01/23/2020 " + "06:30 PM");

let diffInMinutes = (timeEnd - timeStart) / 60000;
let minutes = Math.floor(diff / 60);
```

to get the local time zone's minute difference you have to add the timezone offset when calculation the diff.
you can do so by ->

```
let diffInMinutesWithTZOffset = diff + new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

where diffInMinutesWithTZOffset will produce correct difference according to each timezone.